# text appearing blurred in zoomed mode UITextField/TextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield, uitextview

I've a UIScrollView with 'n' number of UITextField(s) & UITextView(s). Text entered in the UITextField & UITextView appear fine in the normal state(scroll view zoom scale = 1). When ScrollView is zoomed in I scale the UITextField & UITextView rects proportionally w.r.t scrollView zoomScale factor.

The text in zoomed state appears in blurred state when compared to normal state.

Any help in overcoming this problem will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311024/cgaffinetransformmakescale-on-uitextview

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990458/zoom-uilabel-re-render-font-at-correct-size and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448285/how-do-i-reset-after-a-uiscrollview-zoom/451629#451629

Answer (score 1):

All text-related UI elements need redrawing after zooming them in if you want to keep their appearances crystal sharp.

Since this is not an exact duplicate i'll put this links as an answer:

Please check the accepted answers here:

[Zoom UILabel & Re-render font at correct size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990458/zoom-uilabel-re-render-font-at-correct-size)

[How do I reset after a UIScrollView zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448285/how-do-i-reset-after-a-uiscrollview-zoom/451629#451629)

It's quite a lot of work but it pays of in the end. Especially if you have a lot of text-related elements in scrollView.